# Golang SQLBoiler append queries dynamically

Tags: postgresql, go, sqlboiler

I'm trying to dynamically run queries against my Postgres database, but can't fully wrap my head around it.

The solution I'm looking for is one where I can set the query dynamically, perhaps by appending parameters to the final query throughout the code, and then have only one instance of the query being executed.

As mentioned in the title I am using SQLBoiler to interface with Postgres.

Here's what I'm looking for in pseudo code:

```golang
final_query := QueryMod{
    Where("(mt_mas = ? or mt_mem like ?) and mt_group = ?", uint(uid), `%"`+strconv.Itoa(uid)+`"%`, bool(mt_group_bool)),
}

if a == 1 {
    final_query = append(final_query, And(" and mt_important = ?", bool(false)))
} else {
    final_query = append(final_query, And(" and mt_ness = ?", bool(true)))
}

res_mt_count, err := models.MTs(
    final_query,
).All(CTX, DB)
```

Thankful for any help along the way! :)

Comment: What problems did you encounter trying to implement the pseudo-code using real code?

Comment: When running the code above I got the following error: `invalid composite literal type qm.QueryMod` on the line `final_query := QueryMod{`.

Comment: `QueryMod` is an interface type so yes, that expression is illegal. If you want a slice of a type you just need to prepend `[]` in front of that type. e.g. `final_query := []QueryMod{Where(...)}`.

Comment: I tried that, but then i got the following error `cannot use final_query (type []qm.QueryMod) as type qm.QueryMod in argument to models.MTs` on the row `res_mt_count, err := models.MTs(`. Any idea how to move forward?

Comment: You can declare a custom slice type that implements the `QueryMod` interface. Then either use that instead of `[]QueryMod{...}` or keep using `[]QueryMod` but convert `final_query` to the declared slice type before passing it to `MTs`. Or, also, you could just redefine `MTs` to accept `[]QueryMod` instead of just `QueryMod`.

Comment: Example of a custom `QueryMod` slice type: https://play.golang.org/p/F_jHJGKP53C

Comment: Thank you your example worked like a charm! I will post the answer below! Thanks again mkopriva! :)

Answer (score 3):

mkopriva solved my problems with the following solution:

```
type QueryModSlice []qm.QueryMod

func (s QueryModSlice) Apply(q *queries.Query) {
    qm.Apply(q, s...)
}

func main() {
    mods := QueryModSlice{
        qm.Where("(mt_mas = ? or mt_mem like ?) and mt_group = ?", uint(uid), `%"`+strconv.Itoa(uid)+`"%`, bool(mt_group_bool)),
    }

    if a == 1 {
        mods = append(mods, qm.And(" and mt_important = ?", bool(false)))
    } else {
        mods = append(mods, qm.And(" and mt_ness = ?", bool(true)))
    }

    res_mt, err := models.MTs(mods).All(CTX, DB)

}
```

Thanks a bunch! :)